# After Magento 1 security upgrade, the install scripts are not working

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script

After a security version upgrade to version (1.14.3.6) Enterprise all my update scripts don't work.

Whether it's inserting, updating... nothing in the install scripts executes.

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: What is the patch you are applied?  what is the problem please explain clearly